# how to do strict date parsing in python 2.x

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, python-datetime

Here in this example below:

```
from datetime import datetime

#[1]
>>> datetime.strptime("01082018","%m%d%Y")
datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 8, 0, 0) 

#[2]
>>> datetime.strptime("1082018","%m%d%Y")
datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 8, 0, 0)
```

In example 2, since there is no preceding '0', the date was parsed as 8th of oct. Is there a way to do a strict date parsing and fail the same if it does not match the expected pattern.

Or to put it differently is there a way to explicitly ask for two digits for month, day and 4 digits for the year.

To add to my observation:
This behavior would only happen for the month of January except for days [10,20,30,31]

Am I missing something or is it a bug in lib ?

Comment: could there be variants when 182018?

Comment: could this happen with day only? or with month also?

Comment: @py_dude: so far I have observed with months: 

>>> datetime.strptime("1082018","%d%m%Y")
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 10, 0, 0)

Comment: Where do your inputs come from? Are they strings? I think the best thing to do is check the length of the string and if it's less than 8, add a `'0'` to the start.

Comment: @pault: I agree if the length is less than 8, I can raise an exception for pattern mismatch. However, wanted to check if there is something inbuilt with the library that can help.